# Simplifying Ways in OpenStreetMap Data

Tags: python, openstreetmap, simplify

Is there a (current) best practice to simplify ways? I have found:

https://github.com/podolsir/osmosis-simplifyways

But besides not being alive, here (http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.openstreetmap.devel/26854) it says:

> Ok, I found out that osmosis-simplifyways is not compatible with
>   osmosis 0.43.1. It will work with 0.39. But the tool is buggy. It
>   removes nodes from ways where it connects to other ways.

Since I want to use the data for routing I guess it wouldn't work anyway.

Is there some well tested Ramer–Douglas–Peucker implementation to simplify osm data properly?

Comment: In which format are you storing your data? If you are working with postgres/postgis you could run:
ST_Simplify: http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_Simplify.html
or even
ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology: http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology.html
Take a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some hints in the open source code of the [JOSM editor](https://josm.openstreetmap.de), that program has a way-simplify-feature inside.

Or have a look at that JOSM plugin named [RemoveRedundantPoints](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Plugins/RemoveRedundantPoints)

Answer (score -1):

It requires ArcGIS, but see my detailed response here in another GIS StackExchange thread regarding building networks and simplifying data while maintaining the topological structure:

[Building Large Network Datasets from OpenStreetMap in ArcGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156517/building-large-network-datasets-from-openstreetmap-in-arcgis/156558#156558)

Comment: Guess I will write something myself. Still, thanks, guys.